# firefox imacros eval trim ... trims only one side

Tags: javascript, firefox, eval, trim, imacros

everyday imacros gives me another reason to wonder.
i've got this code. i want to trim both sides of extracted string, but it only trims right side.

```
one  +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:\"test1\" EXTRACT=TXT " + "\n";
one  +=  "SET !EXTRACT EVAL(\"var text=\\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\\";var text = text.trim();text;\")" + "\n";
```

before trim:

```
$
$                            
$                                q:
$                                50
$                                
$                                
$
```

after trim:

```
$
$                            
$                                q:
$                                50
```

is this fault of my code?

Comment: your code looks ok, but I recommend you to try to use trim inside javascript script and not inside eval, also you can try to use replace method text.replace(/ /gi,"")

Comment: using trim along with iimGetLastExtract() in js script worked like a charm.